# A Book recommendation for double Integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, book-recommendation

I have a really hard time learning Double Integrals, which I attempted to understand when I first saw the use of polar co-ordinates for Integrals. So my goal is to learn double Integrals and also learn how polar co ordinates is being applied. I'm looking for a book that goes step by step, and which teaches me things like how $dx dy$ changes to $r dr d\theta$, (this is only one example)  etc (everything).

In short I'm looking for something like "Double Integrals with polar co-ordinates for dummies"

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Basic multivariable calculus by Marsden, Tromba and Weinstein.. you can even look into Calculus -Vol2 by Tom M Apostol. Also Thomas Calculus may help

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam thank you so much, il check this out :)

Comment: What about advanced integration in several variables? I have yet to find a good book covering the more complicated techniques of double integration.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar edit that to my question :) I would be glad to find a book that starts with easy things (which helps me) and goes upto advanced complicated stuff (solves problem for you) .

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar.. have you tried calculus by tom m apostol??

Comment: It is waay too low level, barely an introduction.  I am looking for a book *about* multivariable integrals. Not a book about calculus, having a few pages on the topic. Eg a book covering how to solve integrals like
$$
 \iint_S \arctan \left( e^{xy} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
Where $S = \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ x^2 + y^2 \leq 4x\} $

Comment: Have a look at Multivariable Calculus by James Stewart (chapter 15)....

Answer (score 1):

For double integration, I like the following two references:

- Schaum's Outline of Advanced Calculus by Robert Wrede

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Schaums-Outline-Advanced-Calculus-Third/dp/0071623663/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1433163359&sr=8-1&keywords=schaum+outline+advanced+calculus

This has plenty of solved and unsolved problems and explains double integration well.

- Multivariable Calculus by James Stewart

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Multivariable-Calculus-James-Stewart/dp/0538497874/ref=dp_ob_image_bk

Another great reference that I found breaks down double integration well.

Hope that helps.